# How to know when consumer.poll() is called while using @KafkaListener annotation?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I understand that I cannot control when to poll if I use @KafkaListener, and I read from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50244744/spring-kafka-when-is-exactly-consumer-poll-called-behind-the-hood) that

> the next `poll()` is performed after the last message from the previous poll has been processed by the listener.

So I'm wondering how to know when each `poll()` is executed? Or equivalently, how long does it take to process all messages received in each `poll()` call?

I am asking because my program got "Offset commit failed ... The request timed out" exceptions, and I would like to tune my consumer config, i.e. `max.poll.interval.ms` and `max.poll.records`, but I need to know the current performance first.

Here is part of my @KafkaListener method if it helps:

```java
@KafkaListener(id = "dataListener", topics ="${spring.kafka.topic}", containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
public void listen(@Payload(required = false)  ConsumerRecord payload, @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) String partition,
                        @Header(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET)Long offset, @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_MESSAGE_KEY)String messageKey){
    // processing messages
}
```

Comment: @Gary Russell Can you kindly shed some light? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see polling activity by turning on DEBUG logging.

```
this.logger.debug(() -> "Received: " + records.count() + " records");
```

logged after each `poll()`.

Comment: Thanks Gary! With this line I can now locate the [source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/775428b9a8447f50856d6cee5a335c638a05c619/spring-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/kafka/listener/KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java), and for those who use `log4j` as i do, you can set `log4j.logger.org.springframework.kafka.listener=debug` but keep `log4j.logger.org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter=info`, other wise it will log every raw message received.